# Existence of minimum point of function

Tags: real-analysis, continuity

I make an exercise and I stuck on one place. So I have:

Let $I:=\left[0,\frac{\pi}{2}\right]$ and let $f:I\to \mathbb R$ be defined by $f(x):=\sup\{x^2,\cos(x)\}$ for $x \in I$. Show there exists an absolute minimum point $x_0 \in I$ for $f$ on $I$. Show that $x_0$ is a solution to the equation $\cos(x)=x^2$.

**My work**: I have solved the first part. So $x_0$ exists because of Maximum-Minimum Theorem. We have a closed bounded interval and $f$ is continuous (because $f(x):=\sup\{x^2,\cos(x)\}$ I can rewrite to $f(x):=\frac{1}{2} \cdot(x^2+\cos(x))+\frac{1}{2}\cdot \lvert x^2-\cos(x) \rvert$ and by Combinations of continuous functions theorem sum, product and
difference of continuous functions is continuous.) Hence $x_0$ a minimum point exists.

But, I have a problem with the second part. The solution in my book is:

If $\cos(x_0)>x_0^2$ then there exists a $\delta$-neighborhood $V_\delta(x_0) \subseteq I$ on which $f(x)=\cos(x)$, so that $x_0$ is not a minimum point for $f$. So I know a theorem that guarantees the existence of a $\delta$-neighborhood $V_\delta(x_0) \subseteq I$, but why is $f(x)=\cos(x)$ and hence $x_0$ is not a minimum point for $f$, I don't understand. And what if $\cos(x_0)<x_0^2$?

Can somebody explain me it, please?

Thank you for help!

Answer (score 1):

Since $\cos(x_0) > x_0^2$, it follows that $\cos(x) > \frac{\cos(x_0) + x_0^2}{2}$ in a neighborhood $N^1(x_0)$ and that $\frac{\cos(x_0) + x_0^2}{2} > x^2$ in a neighborhood $N^2(x_0)$. Taking $N = N^1(x_0) \cap N^2(x_0)$, we have $x \in N \implies \cos(x) > x^2$, so $f(x) = \cos(x)$.

We have $f(0)=1$ and $f(\frac{\pi}{2})=\frac{\pi^2}{4}$, so $x_0 < \frac{\pi}{2}$.

Taking $x \in N \cap (x_0, \frac{\pi}{2}]$, we have $f(x_0)=\cos(x_0) > \cos(x)=f(x)$, because $\cos$ is decreasing on $[0, \frac{\pi}{2}]$. But this contradicts the fact that $x_0$ is a minimum point for $f$.

The other case is analogous.